# Проверка текстового поля на ввод цифр

Tags: php

Как проверить текстовое поле, получаемое через post на цифры, и вывести ошибку?

Comment: *Как проверить* Регуляркой. PS. Казалось бы, при чём тут теги [mysql] и [phpmyadmin]...

Comment: Советую познакомиться с понятием regexp, погуглите, должно вам помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php). Она выполняет проверку входящей строки на соответствие регулярному выражению. Возвращает `1`, если параметр `pattern` соответствует переданному параметру `subject`, `0` если нет, или `FALSE` в случае ошибки.

В Вашем случае:

```
if (!preg_match('/^\D+$/i', $subject)) {
    echo "Есть цифры";
} else {
    echo "Цифр нет";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте php-функцию is_numeric() — она возвращает false в случае, если аргумент не число. Пример из хелпа:

```
<?php
$tests = array(
    "42", 
    1337, 
    "1e4", 
    "not numeric", 
    array(), 
    9.1
);

foreach ($tests as $element) {
    if (is_numeric($element)) {
        echo "'{$element}' - число", PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "'{$element}' - НЕ число", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

Результат

```
'42' - число
'1337' - число
'1e4' - число
'not numeric' - НЕ число
'Array' - НЕ число
'9.1' - число
```